# CronJobDetail Job Type Full List

Tags: scheduled-job

The official documention for the CronJobDetail object lists only 6 job types.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm

Data Export (0)
Dashboard Refresh (3)
Reporting Snapshot (4)
Scheduled Apex (7)
Report Run (8)
Batch Job (9)

There are clearly more Job Types. I have a Job Type "A" which coordinates to "Reporting Notification". It looks like it is related to subscribing to get report notifications.

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=reports_notifications_home.htm&siteLang=en_US

Does anyone have a full list of Job Types? It does not seem that Salesforce provides this in detail.

Comment: I tweeted to the Salesforce Docs team about this. Hopefully they can update the documentation.

Comment: Yes...doc has been updated...now!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I'm seeing a JobType of '1' which has a Name value of 'Data Export'. The total list of values I'm getting are:
1, 3, 4, 7, 8 and A

I've been trying to figure out how to stop SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler operations that were spawned from a now aborted scheduled batch job, doesn't seem that the JobType is helpful with that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm) has been updated.

```
1—Data Export
3—Dashboard Refresh
4—Reporting Snapshot
6—Scheduled Flow
7—Scheduled Apex
8—Report Run
9—Batch Job
A—Reporting Notification
```

But Salesforce is still introducing new `JobTypes` e.g. `C`,`E`, ... Which are missing in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

E and G corresponds to Job related to your Site.com. You can find the site ID by last phrase of the job name. For more details - https://community.servicemax.com/s/article/Steps-to-Run-Salesforce-Sitemap-Jobs-with-Active-User

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm) lists the names for 1-A. You can also see these by running some Anonymous Apex to look at the picklist values:

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistOptions = new CronJobDetail()
  .getSObjectType()
  .getDescribe()
  .fields.getMap()
  .get('JobType')
  .getDescribe()
  .getPicklistValues();

for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklistItem : picklistOptions) {
  System.debug(picklistItem.getLabel() + ' - ' + picklistItem.getValue());
}
```

But as Damecek mentioned, the document is not being kept up to date.  And, as it turns out, neither is the picklist values returned by the DescribeFieldResult.

---

In order to overcome this shortcoming, at my work, I've been, on occasion trying to record others as I see them, so far I've added E, G, K, T, and X.  I can see job type C in my CronJobDetails, but since it isn't scheduled, I can't figure out the Name value for it.

Here's my current list:

- Data Export - 1
- Dashboard Refresh - 3
- Reporting Snapshot - 4
- Scheduled Flow - 6
- Scheduled Apex - 7
- Report Run - 8
- Batch Job - 9
- Reporting Notification - A
- Sitemap SEO Generation Job - E
- Sitemap SEO Incremental Job - G
- Autonomous Data Loader Job - K
- Report Type Metadata for Search - T
- Standard Report Type Metadata for Search - X

If anyone records any more, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Here's some pictures showing what we see in our org that we based the above data on:
[image: image showing developer console. Uses the query "SELECT Id, Name, JobType FROM CronJobDetail". This is where you can get the JobType number code]
[image: image showing scehduled jobs. This is where you can get the Name of the JobType (by matching up the Job Names)]